# ASP.net OnClick event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I know there are a lot of posts like this one, and I have tried lots of advice and it's not working ... I need help to figure this one out

Just a side not, I am using bootstrap for css and look of my site, this is my code on page

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Log In" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

And code behind my page, don't focus on code itself, my main problem is that on load breakpoint hits Page_load event, but it will not stop at Button1_click

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Mail;
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client age = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    Mail = (inputEmail.Value);
}
```

I have tried to make event fire by adding this on Page_load event

```
Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
Button1.Command += new CommandEventHandler(Button1_Command);
```

And it's not working, a thing that cross my mind is that I manual write Button1_Click method, as for some reason I can not access event page from properties on my button

Comment: Does the button cause a Post though?

Comment: No, it doesn't cause a post ether

Comment: Therein lies your problem. Try a new button, or some other Control. Check your console for JavaScript errors.

Comment: Thanks man ... I found where the problem was, If you want post this as answer to give you points for fast response and help

Comment: It's alright. If the problem was different you should post your own answer as it may help people in the future :)